# First-time iCloud backup of my iPhone took 26 hours

Tags: iphone, icloud

The first time my iPhone backed up with iCloud, it took 26 hours. It seems like a really long time but I do have a lot of video. How long should this take?

Comment: How much data is on the phone? What is the speed of your Internet connection? Settings->General->Usage->Manage Storage will tell you how big the backup was.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it depends on what you consider to be a LOT of videos.  Truthfully a 64 GB Phone filled on a standard Wifi home network should not take more than 10-15 hours at most.  Truth is the easiest way to see what is going on is go to www.icloud.com and check out your icloud space available.

The other thing to take into account is that you only get 5GB Free. You might have run out of space on iCloud and you didnt get the notifications.